# Setting style in Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

i am setting the style for header and one of my last column also got the style i set for the header. This is my code for setting setting style.

```
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(sheetName);

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMergedRow; i++) {
        sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(i, i, 0, numberOfColumns - 1));
        sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
    }

    XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
    int l = row.getLastCellNum() + 1;
    XSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short) l);
    XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
    Font headerFont = workbook.createFont();

    Set<Integer> keyset = data.keySet();
    int rownum = 0;
    for (Integer key : keyset) {
        row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
        Object[] objArr = data.get(key);
        int cellnum = 0;
        for (Object obj : objArr) {
            cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
            if (obj instanceof String)
                cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
            else if (obj instanceof Integer)
                cell.setCellValue((Integer) obj);
            else if (obj instanceof Double)
                cell.setCellValue((Double) obj);
            else if (obj instanceof Number)
                cell.setCellValue((Double) obj);
        }

        cellStyle.setAlignment(XSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(XSSFCellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER);

        /* adding heading style */
        cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_CORNFLOWER_BLUE.getIndex());
        cellStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        headerFont.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);

        headerFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 12);
        cellStyle.setFont(headerFont);

        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/do4IH.png)

how can i set the style only in header?

Comment: Use two styles, one for the header and one for the rest?

Comment: @Gagravarr,i am supposed to use style for the header only and i am setting the style for header only, the thing is i got it in data section column how?

Answer (score 2):

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(sheetName);
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMergedRow; i++) {
    sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(i, i, 0, numberOfColumns - 1));
    sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
}

XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
int l = row.getLastCellNum() + 1;
XSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short) l);
XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
Font headerFont = workbook.createFont();

cellStyle.setAlignment(XSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
cellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(XSSFCellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER);

/* adding heading style */
cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_CORNFLOWER_BLUE.getIndex());
cellStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
headerFont.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);

headerFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 12);
cellStyle.setFont(headerFont);

cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

Set<Integer> keyset = data.keySet();
int rownum = 0;
for (Integer key : keyset) {
    row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
    Object[] objArr = data.get(key);
    int cellnum = 0;
    for (Object obj : objArr) {
        cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
        if (obj instanceof String)
            cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
        else if (obj instanceof Integer)
            cell.setCellValue((Integer) obj);
        else if (obj instanceof Double)
            cell.setCellValue((Double) obj);
        else if (obj instanceof Number)
            cell.setCellValue((Double) obj);
    }
```

move the cellStyle code outside the for loop

Comment: i got not style at all , Not in header section.